# Can't build an app just created using react-native-cli

Tags: android, react-native, android-emulator

I've set up my app using yarn, when I try to build the App (with no modifications) using `react-native run-android` the terminal returns me with the following:

`error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up`

It's worth to say that I'm running an emulated device through Android Studio when I try building the project.

More useful info:

```
echo $ANDROID_HOME
/Users/fhenriques/Library/Android/sdk

echo $JAVA_HOME   
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home
```

When I try to open from Android Studio the build fails at Sync, showing 3 errors, but all pointing to:

`ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :react-native-gpay.`

The same is true for the other two dependencies: `:app@debugAndroidTest` and `:app@debugUnitTest`

---

Comment: Can you try to run app from Android studio using the play icon.

Comment: Thanks for your tip. From Android Studio it seems the problem comes from somewhere else. When it builds shows 3 errors. All referring to ```Could not resolve project :react-native-gpay.```